# What will be the value stored in a variable when it is initialised with extern keyword when it is already declared as a global variable?

Tags: c

When we declare a global variable, it is initialised to its default value. But when we initialise a variable using the `extern` keyword, why does the variable retain the value with which it is initialised using the `extern` keyword?

For instance, in the code below why is the output `9` and not a compile time error? Since there is no external linkage of variable `x` from any other source file, so x has two copies and we are initialising the variable twice so this should be an error.  Please clarify this; I am a bit confused in the flow of this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int x=9;
int x;

int main()
{
    printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As long as the declarations are identical (to the letter) then it's okay to have multiple declarations. It's *definitions* you can't have two (or more) of.

Comment: Why not use `extern int main(void) { printf("%d\n", x); return 0; }`?  It also works.

Answer (score 1):

`extern int x = 9;` means the same as `int x = 9;`.  The `extern` keyword has no effect for a definition that already has external linkage and an initializer.

`int x;` is called a *tentative definition*.

This is described well by C11 6.9.2/2:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and
>   without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a
>   tentative definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an
>   identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then
>   the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
>   equal to 0.

This translation unit *does* contain an external definition for `x`, so the tentative definition has no effect.  It doesn't matter whether the external definition is before or after the tentative definition.

"external definition" means a non-tentative definition at file scope -- not to be confused with `extern` or "external linkage", although in your example `x` does happen to have external linkage.

So your code is exactly the same as:

```
int x = 9;
```

Comment: I just have one confusion , you said that  "extern " keyword has no effect for a definition that already has external linkage and an initializer. " How is the statement translated in general , is it that first the compiler sees that the variable is global so it has external linkage and , therefore, x is initialized to value 9 , and after that keyword extern is taken into consideration .

Comment: Also I am unable to get this para : " If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer equal to 0. " , what is the meaning of "composite type " here ?

Comment: @stackuser "composite type" means the result of combining types of different tentative definitions for the same identifier.  In the case of `int x; int x = 9;` for example, the composite type would be `int` (this is a trivial case)

Comment: There is no "order of events" in `extern int x = 9;`. It is just a definition of variable with external linkage.

Comment: But we can't use the same identifier name with two different data types .Then how can there be a composite data type for an identifier , please explain this more precisely

Comment: @stackuser you can use the same name with compatible types in tentative definitions. `int x; int x;` is one example.  `int a[]; int a[9];` would be another. Also `struct S s;  struct S { int y; } s;`